# Trying to match two addresses columns from two different tables in PostgreSQL. Can't figure it out

Tags: sql, postgresql

It's very basic. I have one table named "AddressPrimary" which consists of 500,000 addresses for a city and has all of them. Has three columns, "id" and "address" and "rentalPrice". Rental price is currently null as I am trying to get rental prices for these addresses.

I have then a new table named "AddressSecondary" that consists of 1,000 addresses that has rental prices. It has three columns, "id", "unmatchedAddress", "rentalPriceGood".

The 1,000 addresses are not in the same format or spelt the same as in "AddressPrimary". Therefore I cannot just upload these rental prices to the correct address. How can I do a quick SQL to compare the 1,000 addresses to the 500,000 to get the best match %, so that the output would be

"Id from AddressPrimary", "address", "umatchedAddress", "rentalPriceGood",

This way I can then export to CSV, and see if the "address" actually does equal "unmatchedAddress" then I can upload the rental prices for these 1,000 properties into Postgres.

Any suggestions. I've read numerous threads online and tried doing it, but it wouldn't produce what I wanted.

Thanks.

Comment: Fuzzy string matching is not a simple question.

Comment: I've figured out how to do an exact match, so out of the 1,000, I got an exact match of 768 addresses. Is there anyway for SQL to try and get a match % and then I can see if its correct or not manually?

I have done an INNER JOIN, where if "AddressPrimary.address" = "AddressSecondary.unmatchedAddress" then the tables join and I get the output I want. Is there a quick way I can make it so its not an exact match? I've tried incorporating '%' but could not get the query to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<->` or `%` operators from [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html).  There are many ways to formulate this, and it isn't clear what you want.  You could look for all matches within a certain cutoff (join with `%` condition), or find the single closest match in AddressPrimary for each AddressSecondary (lateral join using `<->` in an `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT 1`), or find the single closest match but only if it is also within a certain cutoff (combine the two with `%` in WHERE and `<->` in ORDER BY, this might be important for performance).

The simple case with <-> would be:

```
select *, address <-> unmatchedAddress 
from AddressSecondary cross join lateral (
    select * from AddressPrimary order by address <-> unmatchedAddress limit 1
) as foo
```

You also might want to try domain-specific address standardization software.  I think the USPS publishes some of that.

Comment: how do I use the <-> or %? I tried using the % but it was not returning anything. Could you give me a sample SQL query with <-> used? I'm somewhat new to SQL but trying to learn as much as I can.

I would like to try and find the single closest match in AddressPrimary for each AddressSecondary just to see how far or close the match is.

Comment: If % didn't return anything, maybe no match was within the pg_trgm.similarity_threshold.  You might need to play around with that threshold.

Comment: @kencheung7373 Hi do you manage to find  solution I am dealing with a similar problem and got stuck at same point than you. I had two tables with the addresses split in dew columns I had concatenate them into one table, normalizing them. when I try to match the two normalized columns I found a lot of mismatch. how did you resolve it?